# CSS Stylesheet Won't Connect to node.js Page on C9 Platform

Tags: css, node.js, c9.io

This should be fairly straightforward but the style from my CSS file is not connecting to my .ejs file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question but It's bad practice to mention only screenshots. You should mention your code!

Well, In your HTML, You wrote **href="stylesheet.css"**. It should be **href="/stylesheet.css"** if it is in your project's root directory.